# masm assembly fastest way to write a binary file

Tags: winforms, assembly, file-io, masm, hex

I am trying to make a hexadecimal editor in masm assembly. I wrote some code for the writer part of the hexadecimal editor, but it is slow. I tried 2 different versions of the code. The first code loops through and checks what hexadecimal byte is in the text file like A9 and then writes the byte A9 to the output binary file. The second code does the same thing but writes the byte to a buffer and then writes the buffer to the binary file at the end, but for some reason when writing the code to a buffer every time it should write the byte 00 it writes nothing so my binary file has all of the 00 removed from it. Also for some reason both of the codes take exactly the same time to write the binary file. Here are both of the codes

data

```
    local data

 LOCAL hFile  :DWORD
    LOCAL flen    :DWORD
    LOCAL hMem$  :DWORD
     LOCAL hFile2  :DWORD
    LOCAL hBuf$  :DWORD

data

Buffer  db 80 dup (0)
FileBuffer db 9000 dup (0)
FileBufferBytesWritten db 9000 dup (0)
Done db "Done",0
zerozero db 00h,0
zeroone db 01h,0
zerotwo db 02h,0
zerothree db 03h,0
zerofour db 04h,0
zerofive db 05h,0
zerosix db 06h,0
zeroseven db 07h,0
zeroeight db 08h,0
zeronine db 09h,0
zeroA db 0Ah,0
zeroB db 0Bh,0
zeroC db 0Ch,0
zeroD db 0Dh,0
zeroE db 0Eh,0
zeroF db 0Fh,0
onezero db 10h,0
oneone db 11h,0
onetwo db 12h,0
onethree db 13h,0
onefour db 14h,0
onefive db 15h,0
onesix db 16h,0
oneseven db 17h,0
oneeight db 18h,0
onenine db 19h,0
oneA db 1Ah,0
oneB db 1Bh,0
oneC db 1Ch,0
oneD db 1Dh,0
oneE db 1Eh,0
oneF db 1Fh,0
twozero db 20h,0
twoone db 21h,0
twotwo db 22h,0
twothree db 23h,0
twofour db 24h,0
twofive db 25h,0
twosix db 26h,0
twoseven db 27h,0
twoeight db 28h,0
twonine db 29h,0
twoA db 2Ah,0
twoB db 2Bh,0
twoC db 2Ch,0
twoD db 2Dh,0
twoE db 2Eh,0
twoF db 2Fh,0
threezero db 30h,0
threeone db 31h,0
threetwo db 32h,0
threethree db 33h,0
threefour db 34h,0
threefive db 35h,0
threesix db 36h,0
threeseven db 37h,0
threeeight db 38h,0
threenine db 39h,0
threeA db 3Ah,0
threeB db 3Bh,0
threeC db 3Ch,0
threeD db 3Dh,0
threeE db 3Eh,0
threeF db 3Fh,0
fourzero db 40h,0
fourone db 41h,0
fourtwo db 42h,0
fourthree db 43h,0
fourfour db 44h,0
fourfive db 45h,0
foursix db 46h,0
fourseven db 47h,0
foureight db 48h,0
fournine db 49h,0
fourA db 4Ah,0
fourB db 4Bh,0
fourC db 4Ch,0
fourD db 4Dh,0
fourE db 4Eh,0
fourF db 4Fh,0
fivezero db 50h,0
fiveone db 51h,0
fivetwo db 52h,0
fivethree db 53h,0
fivefour db 54h,0
fivefive db 55h,0
fivesix db 56h,0
fiveseven db 57h,0
fiveeight db 58h,0
fivenine db 59h,0
fiveA db 5Ah,0
fiveB db 5Bh,0
fiveC db 5Ch,0
fiveD db 5Dh,0
fiveE db 5Eh,0
fiveF db 5Fh,0
sixzero db 60h,0
sixone db 61h,0
sixtwo db 62h,0
sixthree db 63h,0
sixfour db 64h,0
sixfive db 65h,0
sixsix db 66h,0
sixseven db 67h,0
sixeight db 68h,0
sixnine db 69h,0
sixA db 6Ah,0
sixB db 6Bh,0
sixC db 6Ch,0
sixD db 6Dh,0
sixE db 6Eh,0
sixF db 6Fh,0
sevenzero db 70h,0
sevenone db 71h,0
seventwo db 72h,0
seventhree db 73h,0
sevenfour db 74h,0
sevenfive db 75h,0
sevensix db 76h,0
sevenseven db 77h,0
seveneight db 78h,0
sevennine db 79h,0
sevenA db 7Ah,0
sevenB db 7Bh,0
sevenC db 7Ch,0
sevenD db 7Dh,0
sevenE db 7Eh,0
sevenF db 7Fh,0
eightzero db 80h,0
eightone db 81h,0
eighttwo db 82h,0
eightthree db 83h,0
eightfour db 84h,0
eightfive db 85h,0
eightsix db 86h,0
eightseven db 87h,0
eighteight db 88h,0
eightnine db 89h,0
eightA db 8Ah,0
eightB db 8Bh,0
eightC db 8Ch,0
eightD db 8Dh,0
eightE db 8Eh,0
eightF db 8Fh,0
ninezero db 90h,0
nineone db 91h,0
ninetwo db 92h,0
ninethree db 93h,0
ninefour db 94h,0
ninefive db 95h,0
ninesix db 96h,0
nineseven db 97h,0
nineeight db 98h,0
ninenine db 99h,0
nineA db 9Ah,0
nineB db 9Bh,0
nineC db 9Ch,0
nineD db 9Dh,0
nineE db 9Eh,0
nineF db 9Fh,0
Azero db 0A0h,0
Aone db 0A1h,0
Atwo db 0A2h,0
Athree db 0A3h,0
Afour db 0A4h,0
Afive db 0A5h,0
Asix db 0A6h,0
Aseven db 0A7h,0
Aeight db 0A8h,0
Anine db 0A9h,0
AA db 0AAh,0
AB db 0ABh,0
AC db 0ACh,0
AD db 0ADh,0
AE db 0AEh,0
AF db 0AFh,0
Bzero db 0B0h,0
Bone db 0B1h,0
Btwo db 0B2h,0
Bthree db 0B3h,0
Bfour db 0B4h,0
Bfive db 0B5h,0
Bsix db 0B6h,0
Bseven db 0B7h,0
Beight db 0B8h,0
Bnine db 0B9h,0
BA db 0BAh,0
BB db 0BBh,0
BC db 0BCh,0
BD db 0BDh,0
BE db 0BEh,0
BF db 0BFh,0
Czero db 0C0h,0
Cone db 0C1h,0
Ctwo db 0C2h,0
Cthree db 0C3h,0
Cfour db 0C4h,0
Cfive db 0C5h,0
Csix db 0C6h,0
Cseven db 0C7h,0
Ceight db 0C8h,0
Cnine db 0C9h,0
CA db 0CAh,0
CB db 0CBh,0
CC db 0CCh,0
CD db 0CDh,0
CE db 0CEh,0
CF db 0CFh,0
Dzero db 0D0h,0
Deeone db 0D1h,0
Dtwo db 0D2h,0
Dthree db 0D3h,0
Dfour db 0D4h,0
Dfive db 0D5h,0
Dsix db 0D6h,0
Dseven db 0D7h,0
Deight db 0D8h,0
Dnine db 0D9h,0
DA db 0DAh,0
DeeB db 0DBh,0
DC db 0DCh,0
DeeD db 0DDh,0
DE db 0DEh,0
DeeF db 0DFh,0
Ezero db 0E0h,0
Eone db 0E1h,0
Etwo db 0E2h,0
Ethree db 0E3h,0
Efour db 0E4h,0
Efive db 0E5h,0
Esix db 0E6h,0
Eseven db 0E7h,0
Eeight db 0E8h,0
Enine db 0E9h,0
EA db 0EAh,0
EB db 0EBh,0
EC db 0ECh,0
ED db 0EDh,0
EE db 0EEh,0
EF db 0EFh,0
Fzero db 0F0h,0
Fone db 0F1h,0
Ftwo db 0F2h,0
Fthree db 0F3h,0
Ffour db 0F4h,0
Ffive db 0F5h,0
Fsix db 0F6h,0
Fseven db 0F7h,0
Feight db 0F8h,0
Fnine db 0F9h,0
FA db 0FAh,0
FB db 0FBh,0
FC db 0FCh,0
FD db 0FDh,0
FE db 0FFh,0
FF db 0FFh,0

.data ?

Bytes dd ?
BytesWritten dd ?
```

first code

```
writehexadecimal macro bytetext,byte

      mov eax, cmp$(ADDR Buffer,bytetext)

      .if eax == 0

      invoke WriteFile,hFile2,addr byte,1,addr BytesWritten,NULL

      .endif

EndM

invoke CreateFile, addr FilePathformatted, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0,OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0
mov hFile, eax

invoke GetFileSize,hFile,NULL
mov edi,eax              
          invoke CreateFile,addr FilePath2,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL                                
              mov hFile2, eax              
              xor esi,esi              
              writebinary:

          invoke ReadFile, hFile, ADDR Buffer,2, addr BytesWritten, 0          

          writehexadecimal "00",zerozero
          writehexadecimal "01",zeroone
          writehexadecimal "02",zerotwo
          writehexadecimal "03",zerothree        
          writehexadecimal "04",zerofour
          writehexadecimal "05",zerofive
          writehexadecimal "06",zerosix
          writehexadecimal "07",zeroseven
          writehexadecimal "08",zeroeight
          writehexadecimal "09",zeronine 
          writehexadecimal "0A",zeroA
          writehexadecimal "0B",zeroB
          writehexadecimal "0C",zeroC
          writehexadecimal "0D",zeroD
          writehexadecimal "0E",zeroE
          writehexadecimal "0F",zeroF
          writehexadecimal "10",onezero
          writehexadecimal "11",oneone
          writehexadecimal "12",onetwo
          writehexadecimal "13",onethree        
          writehexadecimal "14",onefour
          writehexadecimal "15",onefive
          writehexadecimal "16",onesix
          writehexadecimal "17",oneseven
          writehexadecimal "18",oneeight
          writehexadecimal "19",onenine 
          writehexadecimal "1A",oneA
          writehexadecimal "1B",oneB
          writehexadecimal "1C",oneC
          writehexadecimal "1D",oneD
          writehexadecimal "1E",oneE
          writehexadecimal "1F",oneF
          writehexadecimal "20",twozero
          writehexadecimal "21",twoone
          writehexadecimal "22",twotwo
          writehexadecimal "23",twothree        
          writehexadecimal "24",twofour
          writehexadecimal "25",twofive
          writehexadecimal "26",twosix
          writehexadecimal "27",twoseven
          writehexadecimal "28",twoeight
          writehexadecimal "29",twonine 
          writehexadecimal "2A",twoA
          writehexadecimal "2B",twoB
          writehexadecimal "2C",twoC
          writehexadecimal "2D",twoD
          writehexadecimal "2E",twoE
          writehexadecimal "2F",twoF
          writehexadecimal "30",threezero
          writehexadecimal "31",threeone
          writehexadecimal "32",threetwo
          writehexadecimal "33",threethree        
          writehexadecimal "34",threefour
          writehexadecimal "35",threefive
          writehexadecimal "36",threesix
          writehexadecimal "37",threeseven
          writehexadecimal "38",threeeight
          writehexadecimal "39",threenine 
          writehexadecimal "3A",threeA
          writehexadecimal "3B",threeB
          writehexadecimal "3C",threeC
          writehexadecimal "3D",threeD
          writehexadecimal "3E",threeE
          writehexadecimal "3F",threeF
          writehexadecimal "40",fourzero
          writehexadecimal "41",fourone
          writehexadecimal "42",fourtwo
          writehexadecimal "43",fourthree        
          writehexadecimal "44",fourfour
          writehexadecimal "45",fourfive
          writehexadecimal "46",foursix
          writehexadecimal "47",fourseven
          writehexadecimal "48",foureight
          writehexadecimal "49",fournine 
          writehexadecimal "4A",fourA
          writehexadecimal "4B",fourB
          writehexadecimal "4C",fourC
          writehexadecimal "4D",fourD
          writehexadecimal "4E",fourE
          writehexadecimal "4F",fourF
          writehexadecimal "50",fivezero
          writehexadecimal "51",fiveone
          writehexadecimal "52",fivetwo
          writehexadecimal "53",fivethree        
          writehexadecimal "54",fivefour
          writehexadecimal "55",fivefive
          writehexadecimal "56",fivesix
          writehexadecimal "57",fiveseven
          writehexadecimal "58",fiveeight
          writehexadecimal "59",fivenine 
          writehexadecimal "5A",fiveA
          writehexadecimal "5B",fiveB
          writehexadecimal "5C",fiveC
          writehexadecimal "5D",fiveD
          writehexadecimal "5E",fiveE
          writehexadecimal "5F",fiveF
          writehexadecimal "60",sixzero
          writehexadecimal "61",sixone
          writehexadecimal "62",sixtwo
          writehexadecimal "63",sixthree        
          writehexadecimal "64",sixfour
          writehexadecimal "65",sixfive
          writehexadecimal "66",sixsix
          writehexadecimal "67",sixseven
          writehexadecimal "68",sixeight
          writehexadecimal "69",sixnine 
          writehexadecimal "6A",sixA
          writehexadecimal "6B",sixB
          writehexadecimal "6C",sixC
          writehexadecimal "6D",sixD
          writehexadecimal "6E",sixE
          writehexadecimal "6F",sixF
          writehexadecimal "70",sevenzero
          writehexadecimal "71",sevenone
          writehexadecimal "72",seventwo
          writehexadecimal "73",seventhree        
          writehexadecimal "74",sevenfour
          writehexadecimal "75",sevenfive
          writehexadecimal "76",sevensix
          writehexadecimal "77",sevenseven
          writehexadecimal "78",seveneight
          writehexadecimal "79",sevennine 
          writehexadecimal "7A",sevenA
          writehexadecimal "7B",sevenB
          writehexadecimal "7C",sevenC
          writehexadecimal "7D",sevenD
          writehexadecimal "7E",sevenE
          writehexadecimal "7F",sevenF
          writehexadecimal "80",eightzero
          writehexadecimal "81",eightone
          writehexadecimal "82",eighttwo
          writehexadecimal "83",eightthree        
          writehexadecimal "84",eightfour
          writehexadecimal "85",eightfive
          writehexadecimal "86",eightsix
          writehexadecimal "87",eightseven
          writehexadecimal "88",eighteight
          writehexadecimal "89",eightnine 
          writehexadecimal "8A",eightA
          writehexadecimal "8B",eightB
          writehexadecimal "8C",eightC
          writehexadecimal "8D",eightD
          writehexadecimal "8E",eightE
          writehexadecimal "8F",eightF
          writehexadecimal "90",ninezero
          writehexadecimal "91",nineone
          writehexadecimal "92",ninetwo
          writehexadecimal "93",ninethree        
          writehexadecimal "94",ninefour
          writehexadecimal "95",ninefive
          writehexadecimal "96",ninesix
          writehexadecimal "97",nineseven
          writehexadecimal "98",nineeight
          writehexadecimal "99",ninenine 
          writehexadecimal "9A",nineA
          writehexadecimal "9B",nineB
          writehexadecimal "9C",nineC
          writehexadecimal "9D",nineD
          writehexadecimal "9E",nineE
          writehexadecimal "9F",nineF
          writehexadecimal "A0",Azero
          writehexadecimal "A1",Aone
          writehexadecimal "A2",Atwo
          writehexadecimal "A3",Athree        
          writehexadecimal "A4",Afour
          writehexadecimal "A5",Afive
          writehexadecimal "A6",Asix
          writehexadecimal "A7",Aseven
          writehexadecimal "A8",Aeight
          writehexadecimal "A9",Anine 
          writehexadecimal "AA",AA
          writehexadecimal "AB",AB
          writehexadecimal "AC",AC
          writehexadecimal "AD",AD
          writehexadecimal "AE",AE
          writehexadecimal "AF",AF
          writehexadecimal "B0",Bzero
          writehexadecimal "B1",Bone
          writehexadecimal "B2",Btwo
          writehexadecimal "B3",Bthree        
          writehexadecimal "B4",Bfour
          writehexadecimal "B5",Bfive
          writehexadecimal "B6",Bsix
          writehexadecimal "B7",Bseven
          writehexadecimal "B8",Beight
          writehexadecimal "B9",Bnine 
          writehexadecimal "BA",BA
          writehexadecimal "BB",BB
          writehexadecimal "BC",BC
          writehexadecimal "BD",BD
          writehexadecimal "BE",BE
          writehexadecimal "BF",BF
          writehexadecimal "C0",Czero
          writehexadecimal "C1",Cone
          writehexadecimal "C2",Ctwo
          writehexadecimal "C3",Cthree        
          writehexadecimal "C4",Cfour
          writehexadecimal "C5",Cfive
          writehexadecimal "C6",Csix
          writehexadecimal "C7",Cseven
          writehexadecimal "C8",Ceight
          writehexadecimal "C9",Cnine 
          writehexadecimal "CA",CA
          writehexadecimal "CB",CB
          writehexadecimal "CC",CC
          writehexadecimal "CD",CD
          writehexadecimal "CE",CE
          writehexadecimal "CF",CF
          writehexadecimal "D0",Dzero
          writehexadecimal "D1",Done
          writehexadecimal "D2",Dtwo
          writehexadecimal "D3",Dthree        
          writehexadecimal "D4",Dfour
          writehexadecimal "D5",Dfive
          writehexadecimal "D6",Dsix
          writehexadecimal "D7",Dseven
          writehexadecimal "D8",Deight
          writehexadecimal "D9",Dnine 
          writehexadecimal "DA",DA
          writehexadecimal "DB",DeeB
          writehexadecimal "DC",DC
          writehexadecimal "DD",DeeD
          writehexadecimal "DE",DE
          writehexadecimal "DF",DeeF
          writehexadecimal "E0",Ezero
          writehexadecimal "E1",Eone
          writehexadecimal "E2",Etwo
          writehexadecimal "E3",Ethree        
          writehexadecimal "E4",Efour
          writehexadecimal "E5",Efive
          writehexadecimal "E6",Esix
          writehexadecimal "E7",Eseven
          writehexadecimal "E8",Eeight
          writehexadecimal "E9",Enine 
          writehexadecimal "EA",EA
          writehexadecimal "EB",EB
          writehexadecimal "EC",EC
          writehexadecimal "ED",ED
          writehexadecimal "EE",EE
          writehexadecimal "EF",EF
          writehexadecimal "F0",Fzero
          writehexadecimal "F1",Fone
          writehexadecimal "F2",Ftwo
          writehexadecimal "F3",Fthree        
          writehexadecimal "F4",Ffour
          writehexadecimal "F5",Ffive
          writehexadecimal "F6",Fsix
          writehexadecimal "F7",Fseven
          writehexadecimal "F8",Feight
          writehexadecimal "F9",Fnine 
          writehexadecimal "FA",FA
          writehexadecimal "FB",FB
          writehexadecimal "FC",FC
          writehexadecimal "FD",FD
          writehexadecimal "FE",FE
          writehexadecimal "FF",FF

          sub edi,2

          .if edi == 0
          invoke CloseHandle,hFile
          invoke CloseHandle,hFile2
          invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr Done, offset BoxCaption, NULL
          ret          
          .endif

          jmp writebinary
```

second code

```
writehexadecimal macro bytetext,byte

      mov eax, cmp$(ADDR Buffer,bytetext)

      .if eax == 0

      invoke lstrcat,addr FileBuffer,addr byte
      inc esi 

      .endif

EndM

invoke CreateFile, addr FilePathformatted, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0,OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0
mov hFile, eax

invoke GetFileSize,hFile,NULL
mov edi,eax              
          invoke CreateFile,addr FilePath2,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL

          mov hFile2, eax              
          xor esi,esi              
          writebinary:              
          invoke ReadFile, hFile, ADDR Buffer,2, addr BytesWritten, 0
```

**same writehexadecimal list as the first code. stack overflow said I hit the character limit so I don't need to write that list again**

```
          sub edi,2

          .if esi == 9000

          invoke WriteFile,hFile2,addr FileBuffer,sizeof FileBuffer,addr BytesWritten,NULL

          .endif

          .if edi == 0
          invoke WriteFile,hFile2,addr FileBuffer,esi,addr FileBufferBytesWritten,NULL
          invoke CloseHandle,hFile
          invoke CloseHandle,hFile2
          invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr Done, offset BoxCaption, NULL
          ret          
          .endif

          jmp writebinary
```

so my question is can anyone help me make this code faster so it is kind of instant instead of taking 5 minutes to write a binary file that is 1mb size.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `lstrcat` to add data to your `FileBuffer` (you shouldn't use `lstrcat` *period*, as it is unsafe). Each time you concatenate one byte, it will have to calculate the current length of the string (`FileBuffer`) that you're appending to, which will take longer and longer as the string grows. Doing this also has the side-effect that a byte with the value `0` won't be appended, since `0` is the string terminator (i.e. `lstrcat` will think that you're trying to append an empty string).

A much better approach would be to simply keep a pointer that holds the address of the first free byte in the buffer, and each time you want to concatenate a byte you write it to that address and then increment the pointer. Something like this:

```
.data?
bufferPtr dd ?
; (other data follows)

.code
mov bufferPtr,OFFSET FileBuffer
; (other code follows)

mov ebx,bufferPtr
mov [ebx],al      ; store one byte in the buffer
inc ebx           ; point to the next byte in the buffer
mov bufferPtr,ebx
```

You could try to keep the pointer in a register at all times if you know that you've got a register that won't be changed by any other part of the code. But to begin with, something like the above should suffice.

Also, calling `ReadFile` for every 2 bytes in the input file is a bit wasteful. Read a big chunk of data (the whole file if possible) into a buffer and then grab 2-byte chunks from that buffer.

And there's absolutely no reason for having 256 different variables just for storing the values `00h..FFh`, or having 256 different calls to `writehexadecimal`. Make `writehexadecimal` a procedure and call it from a loop that iterates from `00h` to `FFh`. You'll save hundreds of lines of code (and a lot of typing on your part).

Comment: can you show an example of how to add a byte to a certain part or point like the second paragraph talks about. I understand what you mean by keeping a counter to know where to put the byte, but how do you put the byte in a certain part or point.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to masm and assembly. I still cant get it to work. I tried putting the 4 lines of code that you gave in the macro part and then I put the 1 line of code that you gave right before my loop part,and the results are that it writes 00 in the entire file. I change the al to offset byte so it would put in 06h into it but then the program would just freeze. also at the end when I write the file what am I writing to the file ebx or FileBuffer or bufferPtr  thank you for all of your help